# Dynamic formula autofill

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, autofill

I would like to know how may i convert this code into dynamic range autofill for the column I to enable the freedom of editing the excel sheet at a later time without the need to adjust the vba code.

```
Sub Rowcount()
    'Charles, M
    Dim H As Long
    Set sh = Worksheets("Report-Charles, M")


    H = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Range("I2:I" & H).Formula = "=IF((AND(OR(E2=""Unrated"",E2=""""),OR(G2<>""Unrated"",G2<>""""))),G2,IF(E2>=""4,25"",""High Performance"",IF(E2<""3,35"",""Low Performance"",IF(AND(E2>=""3,35"",E2<""4,25""),""Medium Performance"",""Unrated""))))"

    MsgBox (H) & "Rows have been Autofilled with 3 scale Rating Results"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the AutoFill function:

```
Range("I2:I" & H).AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I2000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Should `Range("I2:I" & H).AutoFill` be simply `Range("I2").AutoFill` ?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter since all his fields ("I2:I" & H) contain the same base. Both should work.

Comment: Go back and test it. You will find out that you are wrong.I did.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are only implicitly referencing the **Report-Charles, M** as the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) to put the [.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) into; not explicitly with direct reference.

Second, To assign the formula, use a direct [.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) write, the [Range.AutoFill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) or the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx).

Lastly, writing a formula [.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) through VBA should be done with EN-US syntax and regional settings. If you want to use non-EN-US regional settings like `3,35` or `4,25` then use the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx).

Above all else, treat numbers as numbers; not as text-that-look-like-numbers.

```
with Worksheets("Report-Charles, M")
     h = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    .Range("I2:I" & H).FormulaLocal = _
      "=IF((AND(OR(E2=""Unrated"", E2=TEXT(,)), OR(G2<>""Unrated"", G2<>TEXT(,)))), G2, IF(E2>=4,25, ""High Performance"", IF(E2<3,35, ""Low Performance"", ""Medium Performance"")))"
    .Range("I2:I" & H).Formula = _
      "=IF((AND(OR(E2=""Unrated"", E2=TEXT(,)), OR(G2<>""Unrated"", G2<>TEXT(,)))), G2, IF(E2>=4.25, ""High Performance"", IF(E2<3.35, ""Low Performance"", ""Medium Performance"")))"
end with

with Worksheets("Report-Charles, M")
     'any of the following will fill column I with formulas to the last row in .UsedRange
     'all of the following assumes a valid formula in I2
     h = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    .Range("I2:I" & H).Formula = .Range("I2").Formula
    .Range("I2:I" & H).FillDown
    .Range("I2:I" & H).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlAutoFill
    .Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("I2:I" & H), Type:=xlFillDefault
end with
```

I've shortened one `IF` condition since the `AND` was unnecessary and Medium was the default response. Using `TEXT(,)` is the same as saying `""` and does not have to double-up double-quotes.